# How to enforce to use iam policy in aws lamda python

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

Let me describe my issue.
I have created an iam policy - **Policy A**
There are two aws managed iam policies - **Policy B** and **Policy C**

I want to add a condition to the account, if anyone use Policy B or Policy C for their iam role, they must attach Policy A
I hope this can be done using lamda, but not sure. If there any other way, please be kind to share with me.

Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Someone could presumably bypass such a restriction by simply including the individual policy statements from B and C in policy D and using that instead. Ideally, your users would have a limited set of roles from which to choose and they would include policies B and C as needed.

Comment: How about you just create a role with Policy A,B,C attached and force people use that role?